# Connection failed with hdp services

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

i am using hdp 3.0.1 ,about to two days ago, i am unable to use hadoop,hdfs,hive,spark, and i also restart my services from ambari web UI but it was failed to recover [image]

Comment: Can you provide full logs of namenode error? It may be giving error because of OOM issue.

Comment: dude its too long and i cannot realize the error and cannot found on internet clearly that i can understand

Comment: "_NameNode is still in SafeMode_" -- if you are seeing this for extended time you can start familiarizing yourself with HDFS recovery procedures.

Comment: it had been took  4 days already , can suggest any other way